# In vue.js, declare the "var ~ = new vue" every time?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

new in vue.js and trying to make simple webpage
But just wondering that am I doing right?

This is my code here

```
<div class="title">{{ page_title }}</div>
<div class="name">{{ username }}</div>
<div class="date">{{ date }}</div>

var title = new Vue ({
  el: '.title',
  data : {
     page_title :'This is title'
   }
})


var name = new Vue ({
  el: '.name',
  data : {
     username :'This is your name'
   }
})

var date = new Vue ({
  el: '.date',
  data : {
     Date :'Todays date'
   }
})
```

Do I have to declare the "var ~ = new vue" every time?
Or is there any way to make more simpler?

Comment: Why not just create a wrapper component with a template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create as many vue-instances as you like of course, they are pretty lightweight, it's more about managing your code and splitting it into re-usable chunks.

Just putting Li357's comment into code:

```js
Vue.component('page', {
  template: `
  <div>
    <div class="title">{{ page_title }}</div>
    <div class="name">{{ username }}</div>
    <div class="date">{{ date }}</div>
  </div>`,
  props: ["title"],
  data() {
    return {
      page_title: 'This is ' + this.title,
      username: 'This is your name',
      date: 'Todays date'
    };
  }
});

new Vue({
  template: `
  <div>
  <h1>This is my app</h1>
  <page title="TITLE!" />
  </div>`,
  el: '.my-app',
})
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-app"></div>
```

While I sure can imagine date or username elements as reusable components, if you are just displaying a value and nothing more then I wouldn't bother.